# The possible sound change when /t/ sound is preceded by fricatives or affricatives

Tags: english, phonetics, pronunciation, theoretical-linguistics, consonants

Here, I am talking about the assimilated /t/ sound that is one of the most common features of Standard Southern British English (such as /t/ at the beginning of a syllable, *time, task, Twitter, twice*, etc.) as they are enunciated as /tts/ (neither full /ts/ nor /t/). If you pronounce /t/ sound as /t/ sound, there will not be any sound change taking place and I am afraid that you will not help me with this.

However, when these /tts/ sounds are preceded by affricatives or fricatives in a connected speech, I have noticed a possible sound change that the tongue will NOT necessarily get to the position that /tts/ is usually pronounced (right above the front teeth and below the alveolar ridge) but rather the tongue would simple be like hanging in the middle of the space without touching any place that it is supposed to touch when pronouncing /tts/ sound. There are also two exceptions towards this possible rule, first when /tts/ sound is stressed or second when there is a gap between these two sounds (as you read word by word)

I will give several examples for you as follows;

1. It i**s t**ime to go to bed! (/ts/+/tts/)
2. He is my Engli**sh t**eacher. (/ʃ/+/tts/)
3. She is my Chine**se t**eacher. (/z/+/tts/)
4. i will see you ne**xt t**ime (/s/+/tts/)

My question is is it a common sound change in English (especially in Southern British English) and the native speakers may not necessarily be conscious of this. Thanks, guys!

Comment: What you write as /tts/ is the affrication of syllable-onset /t/, pronounced as [tˢʰ] (with varying levels of affrication and aspiration). There is not usually any change in this pronunciation after fricatives (or sibilants, as all your examples are), as far as I know. It may be that the level of affrication tends to be slightly lower after sibilants than in isolation, but if it is, I’d say it’s incidental and at best inconsistent. It certainly doesn’t occur after other fricatives (e.g., ‘I’ve taken’).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you very much for your reply about the correct term for /tts/ (/tsh/)  But can i ask the corresponding term for the assibilated /d/ sound as in /ddz/?

Comment: That would be [dᶻ], which is less ubiquitous than [tˢ], but still relatively common in SE British.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you very much for your reply about the correct term for /tts/ (/tsh/)  But can i ask the corresponding term for the assibilated /d/ sound as in /ddz/? And for the answer towards the rule of it, it was my mistake that i should have been more specific about them that it should only be limited to alveolar fricatives and Alveopalatal fricatives and affricatives together with /ts/ /dz/ /tr/ /dr/.  I strongly doubt that this sound change only appears occasionally that you will NOT be able to actually pronounce /tsh/ the same way in other situations.

Comment: I don’t understand the last sentence in your comment (it seems to break down grammatically halfway through) – what exactly is it you strongly doubt?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What I meant was that you can NOT possibly pronounce any /tsh/ sound right after these alveolar fricatives and Alveopalatal fricatives and affricatives the same way that you would pronounce /tsh/ in its own.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You can simply give it a go. When you say 'its time to go' the /tsh/ sound in the word 'time' would be enunciated in a different way that it does NOT get to the place where you would normally pronounce /tsh/ sound but being sounded like it is in the middle of the oral space instead (NB: you have to read the sentence without any stress on the word time and there should be any interval between its and time )

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet a typo for the last comment: It should NOT have any interval. cos it only happens when words are connected

Comment: That is simply not true. I can easily pronounce it exactly the same whether I say ‘a time to go’ or ‘it’s time to go’. No difference at all, and the same aspiration and affrication. In rapid speech, especially if I reduce _it’s_ to just _’s_, I may well treat the cluster as syllable-initial /st/, which means there’s no affrication or aspiration on the /t/, but it’s entirely optional, and it’s _only_ an option in cases where it’s possible to analyse the cluster as syllable-initial – in your examples 2 and 3, it’s not an option for me at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you very much for your reply! I was just wondering do you pronounce /t/ sound in its base form or /tsh/ form in any given context regardless of this possible sound change?

Comment: I – like most English-speakers – pronounce it as affricated and aspirated [tˢʰ] in absolute stressed syllable onset, that is, when it comes first in a stressed (or secondarily stressed) syllable; as plain [t] when part of the cluster /st/ in the same syllable; and when it’s syllable-final between vowels, varyingly as a tap [ɾ], a plain [d ~ t] or a glottal stop [ʔ]. As long as the /t/ is treated as being in absolute onset in a stressed syllable, it will almost invariably be [tˢʰ], regardless of what comes before it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you for your professional answers to my questions! I was wondering would it be ok for you to listen to my pronunciation in this regard? I have no idea how I could make it through this.